# Are there any future regulations planned for electric multi-motor LSAs?

Tags: faa-regulations, general-aviation, light-sport-aircraft, electric-engine

It seems with electric control of the multi engine configuration, such as with NASA's new leap tech technology, that there should be a way to use multiple motors in the LSA category. Is there anything in the works regarding regulations for this type of aircraft in the LSA category?

Comment: Last I read, the FAA hadn't made provision for manned electric aircraft of any type. It's possible that multi-rotor electric designs would constitute a new class (or even multiple new classes) of aircraft. It's probable that such a concept will (or won't) be proven in the experimental aircraft community. If it represents a viable model for commercial development, external pressure would force the FAA to acknowledge, and regulate it.

Comment: At least in the US, LSA certification is the purview of [ASTM F37](http://www.astm.org/COMMITTEE/F37.htm). They don't seem to have a [subcommittee](http://www.astm.org/COMMIT/SUBCOMMIT/F37.htm) dedicated to multi-motor anything, and I didn't dig deeply enough to see whether the existing committee has any standards for single-engine electric LSAs.

Comment: As for Europe, currently the issue is not considered. Currently multi engine configurations do have certification advantages as an engine failure is not seen as critical as for single/double engine configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Light-Sport is a category for pilot certification and flight rules. The aircraft themselves are simply part 23 normal category risk classification level one, low speed.

Part 23 was fully rewritten in 2016 it now describes the desired safety outcome but lets manufacturers develop new methods of complying, nothing is bias against electric multi-motor planes in the new part 23.

The issue is that the pilot must be rated for multi-engine operation and you must have at least a private pilot certificate for the multi-engine rating. Most multi engine training is actually about operating with an engine failure and the associated aerodynamics.

Comment: Can you edit your response and provide a link to the new Part 23 rules? Can you provide an article that asserts the same opinion you've expressed here about the new rules?